# Access and write data structure data to file, but cant access it in try catch PrintWriter

Tags: java, eclipse, data-structures, static, try-catch

Im trying to write data from a Double Linked data structure into a file, but cant find a way to print it within the Printwriter try catch block:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Start with the empty list */
    LinkedList lk = new LinkedList();
    Order x = new Order("1", "x", 1);
    Order y = new Order("2", "y", 1);
    DoubleNode dll = new DoubleNode();
    File f = new File("/Users/Dell/Documents/product.txt");

    Product a = new Product("1", "a", 1, 1, 1.);
    Product b = new Product("2", "b", 2, 2, 2.);
    Product c = new Product("3", "c", 3, 3, 3.);
    Product d = new Product("4", "d", 4, 4, 4.);
    Product e = new Product("5", "e", 5, 5, 5.);

    dll.append(b);
    dll.push(d);
    dll.push(a);
    dll.append(c);
    dll.InsertAfter(dll.head.next, e);
    System.out.println("Created DLL is: ");
    dll.printlistF(dll.head);

    String filePath;
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        filePath = f.getCanonicalPath();
    }
    catch(IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (f.exists()) {
        System.out.println("File exist.");
        System.out.println("File is readable: " + f.canRead());
        System.out.println("File is writeable: " + f.canWrite());
        System.out.println("File is location: " + f.getName());

    }

    try {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(f);
        dll.printlistF(dll.head); //THIS IS THE PLACE I CANT FIGURE IT OUT
        output.close();

    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("ERROR"+e2);
    }

}
```

But this would require me to create a new DoubleNode inside the try catch block, and when i tried to make dll static, it said "illegal modifier, only final is permitted". So what should i do? I don't know enough about programming terms to search for similar topic in here, so if anyone have links to them it would be appreciated.

Comment: static members will belong to the class itself as opposed to a specific instance of that class. You cannot use the static keyword modifier within a method as you are currently within that instance. If you want the variable to be static, you would need to declare it at class level.

Comment: You just opened the file for writing (`new PrintWriter(f)`) and assigned that to local variable `output`, so don't you think that the `printlistF` method used to write the data structure, might perhaps *need* that value, i.e. the `output` value?!?!? E.g. `dll.printlistF(output);`, since it shouldn't need the `dll.head` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this would require me to create a new DoubleNode inside the try catch block,

That is not true.  This line:

```
    dll.printlistF(dll.head); //THIS IS THE PLACE I CANT FIGURE IT OUT
```

will work just as well as this line from earlier in the code:

```
    dll.printlistF(dll.head);
```

Your actual problem seems to be that you need to tell `printlistF` where to print the data.  To do that, you need to:

- add a `PrintWriter` parameter to the `printlistF` method declaration which will be the *destination* for the output.
- open the destination within the try block (you have done that) and pass it as an argument in the `printlistF` call.

> and when i tried to make dll static, it said "illegal modifier, only final is permitted".

1. It is not should not be necessary to do that, and it probably wouldn't help in this case.
2. The `dll` variable is a local variable.  Local variables cannot be declared as static.
3. Static variables are usually a **bad idea** in OO programs.  If you find yourself wanting to declare a static, there is typically a problem with your application design.

---

Finally, there is something wrong with your design if you need to print a list like this:

```
dll.printlistF(dll.head);
```

In a good API design, the `head` field would be an *internal* implementation detail, and it should be hidden; i.e. declared as `private`.  And instead of passing `dll.head` as a parameter, the print method should use the `head` of the target object; i.e. `this.head`.

Comment: Right. Can you provide me with the how to add the PrintWriter parameter to my printlistF?

Comment: Err ... what?  You clearly already know how to declare parameters.  You have done it in the `main` method declaration, and at least 4 times in your DoubleNode class.

Comment: '<public boolean searchCusName(Node head, String x) {
  // check if empty + not found
  if (head == null) {
   System.out.println("Order not found. List could be empty.");
   return false;
  }

  // if head is the target
  if (head.data.getCus_name() == x) {
   System.out.println("Found Order.");
   head.data.print();
   return true;
  }
  // call it self until found
  return searchCusName(head.next, x);
 }>'

This line of code. i cant make it to use this.head instead of Node head, and im not sure what the problem is. My vocab is limited, so searching doesnt help much.

Comment: Now i cant even edit that comment. God is this embarrassing.

Comment: If you want to ask about other parts of your code, I suggest you ask a new question, and make sure to include the code that you are asking about in the question.